# Can sqlalchemy be as smart as copy command when to import data into database?

Tags: types, sqlalchemy

Create a simple database and table;

```
create database sample;
create table data(id serial,f1 boolean);
```

Prepare data.txt which contain only one character in:

```
vim data.txt
0
```

`wq` ,save and exit.We can import it with copy command:

```
\copy data(f1) from 'data.txt'
```

The copy command can automatically convert `0` as boolean `false` during import.

```
sample=# select * from data;
 id | f1 
----+----
  1 | f
(1 row)
```

Let's import it with sqlalchemy's add method:

```
#prepare database 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_pass = 'xxxxx'
db_ip = '127.0.0.1'
engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:{}@{}/sample".\
                           format(db_pass,db_ip),future=True)

Base = declarative_base()
class Tdata(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data" 
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    f1 = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Boolean, nullable=True)
    def __init__(self, f1):
        self.f1=f1 

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sess = Session()

#get the data
fh = open('/tmp/data.txt','r')
raw = fh.readline().strip()
row = Tdata(raw)

#try to write
sess.add(row)
sess.commit()
```

Raise error:

```
raise TypeError("Not a boolean value: %r" % (value,))
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Not a boolean value: '0'
```

fix it:

```
sess.rollback()
raw = bool(int(raw))
row = Tdata(raw)
sess.add(row)
sess.commit()
```

We have to convert data type into boolean for field `f1` with `raw = bool(int(raw))`,copy command can convert it automatically,what about many boolean type fields in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would adding a custom type work for you? You can use `sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator`

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator


class BooleanType(TypeDecorator):
    impl = sqlalchemy.Boolean

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return value == '1'


class Tdata(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data"
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    f1 = sqlalchemy.Column(BooleanType, nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, f1):
        self.f1 = f1
```

Notice that in column `f1` I have changed `sqlalchemy.Boolean` to `BooleanType`, which is the the custom type created, this will convert `'1'` to `True` and anything else to `False`.

`value == '1'` that is responsible for the conversion, you can tweak that condition as per your needs.

You can then use `BooleanType` for any column where you automatically want to convert `'0'` or `'1'` to a Boolean value.

You do not have to change the rest of your code, you can add it normally like so

```
row = Tdata(raw)
```